# What's the tractable data size for Sparse PCA or LASSO?

Tags: r, lasso, sparse

I'm up to perform certain kinds of sparse decomposition methods on my dataset. However, I'm not sure: what's the tractable data size for the Sparse Decomposition methods?

The dataset is a $10^3\times10^5$ binary matrix, and the expected methods are Sparse PCA, which aims to find a decomposition with minimized coordinate L1-norm and positive constraint.

I found these things useful:

[penalized package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/penalized/index.html) for R language.

[nsprcomp pacakge](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/nsprcomp/index.html) for R

Comment: The matrix isn't *that* big (less than 1 GB). A conventional non-sparse approach should already do the trick just fine. I suggest trying this before you get out the big guns.

Comment: "Tractable" is a function of your hardware as much as it's a function of your data. Will you be running this on conventional hardware? A supercomputer? A toaster? Pen and paper?

Comment: @DavidMarx I'm on my PC only. No parallel clusters, no workstation.

Answer (score 3):

It depends on how you structure the problem.  If you store the data as a sparse matrix, your datasets can get pretty large before you have a problem.  e.g:

```
#Adapted from:
#http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/Matrix/html/sparseMatrix.html
library(Matrix)
nrow <- 1e3
ncol <- 1e5
nnz <- nrow*ncol*.25
M1 <- sparseMatrix(i = sample(nrow, nnz, replace = TRUE),
                 j = sample(ncol, nnz, replace = TRUE),
                 dims = c(nrow, ncol))
```

However, the tradoff is that there's no sparse methods for PCA and sparse PCA that I know of.  You can do SVD using [irlba](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/irlba/index.html), which is pretty closely related to PCA:

```
library(irlba)
SVD <- irlba(M1, nv=25, nu=0) #Takes a long time
PCs <- M1 %*% SVD$v
head(PCs) #Not true principle components, but close
```

You can also do lasoo regression using [glmnet](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/glmnet/index.html):

```
library(glmnet)
betas <- runif(ncol)
betas[sample(ncol, ncol-50)] <- 0
betas[betas!=0]
Y <- as.numeric(M1 %*% betas + runif(nrow))/10
model <- cv.glmnet(M1, Y, alpha=1)
CF <- coef(model, model$lambda.1se)
as.numeric(CF[CF!=0])
```

However, if you truly want to do sparse PCA, you'll have to use one of the packages you referenced (or something similar), which require dense matrices, and which will probably choke on a 1e3 * 1e5 matrix.

Comment: Exactly. I cannot even assign that large a matrix. Memory overflow for my data.

Comment: BTW, I'm trying to use Sparse PCA and it cannot be achieved by classical PCA since constrians other than minimizing square error is applied.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned the glmnet package can handle datasets with thousands of variables without too many problems.

I just tried doing a PCA on a 1e3 * 1e5 matrix in base R, and it actually worked! Took some time, though (about 5 minutes). Memory usage never went above 3.5GB. This would be a good time to install a multithreaded BLAS, if you'll be doing these analyses frequently.

Comment: What package are you using? I got a memory error for that.

Comment: Just `prcomp` in the stats package. This is with R 3.0.1 64-bit, on a Windows 7 machine with 12GB memory.

Comment: Bloody briliant memory. I've 4GB.